# Swift package calling /usr/bin/swift errors with `Failed to open macho file...Too many levels of symbolic links` only when running from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftpm

I am developing a command line app in Swift which will call out to `swift` in order to initialize packages, compile things, test things, etc.
I am using the swift package manager and Xcode.
In my tool, I call `swift` from a `Process`.
If I am running my tool from the command line, this works fine.
However, if I am running my tool from Xcode, some strange things are printed to standard error.
In particular, I get

```
Failed to open macho file at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

What is causing this? Is there some way I can avoid it, or can I just not run/test this utility from Xcode?

Here are reproduction steps:

```
mkdir XcodeRedirectionTest
cd XcodeRedirectionTest
swift package init
open Package.swift
```

Then in `Tests/XcodeRedirectionTestTests/XcodeRedirectionTestTests.swift`, paste

```swift
import XCTest

final class XcodeRedirectionTestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        let process = Process()
        process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/swift"
        process.arguments = ["--version"]

        let standardOutput = Pipe()
        let standardError = Pipe()

        process.standardOutput = standardOutput
        process.standardError = standardError

        process.launch()
        process.waitUntilExit()

        guard let output = String(data: standardOutput.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8) else { XCTFail(); return }
        guard let error = String(data: standardError.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8) else { XCTFail(); return }

        XCTAssertEqual(process.terminationReason, .exit)
        XCTAssertEqual(process.terminationStatus, 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(error, "")
        XCTAssert(output.starts(with: "Apple Swift version 5.4"))
    }
}
```

Testing in Xcode fails with

```
file://.../XcodeRedirectionTest/Tests/XcodeRedirectionTestTests/XcodeRedirectionTestTests.swift: test failure: XcodeRedirectionTestTests.testExample() failed: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("2021-05-18 19:43:18.084463-0400 swift[2836:4100702] Failed to open macho file at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
") is not equal to ("")
```

That is (so you don't have to scroll (as much)), the standard error ends up being

```
Failed to open macho file at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

However, running `swift test` from the command line succeeds. No standard error!

If it matters, I am running Xcode 12.5 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to narrow this down to the environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE`. It seems that Xcode sets this to `1` when running programs. If this variable is unset, the error is not displayed. The code I used to accomplish this is

```swift
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment.keys.contains("OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE") {
    var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    env["OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE"] = nil
    process.environment = env
}
```

This requires more testing to understand the relationship between the `PWD` passed in the environment and `Process.currentDirectoryURL`, but this at least gets the ball rolling.

Comment: It's also possible to set environment vars in Xcode's Scheme editor under `Arguments`